# CitiBank Branch in Leipzig

Tags: germany, money, leipzig

I'm searching for a Citibank branch in Leipzig.

I've checked google maps and it's not really updated because the one that was mentioned in Goethestrasse was changed into a TargoBank.

Comment: Are you sure there are Citibank branches in Germany? Only Germany is missing from the country list on the [CitiBank Worldwide branch and ATM finder](https://online.citibank.com/US/GCL/citilocator/flow.action), and I see lots of articles about them selling their German retail arm a few years ago...

Comment: "The German retail banking arm of Citibank, which was sold to Crédit Mutuel in December 2008, was formally rebranded Targobank" - there are no more Citibank branches in Germany

Comment: oh , and does that mean that Targobank couldn't perform Citibank actions for former citibank customers ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think so

Comment: i've went to targo bank and they are offering such services for CitiBank clients , thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

The German retail banking arm of Citibank, which was sold to Crédit Mutuel in December 2008 and formally rebranded Targobank. So you cannot find any Citibank branch in Germany.

You can still find some Citibank adresses in Internet, but the information there is just obsolete and if you go there you will find a Targobank branch.

But as you already mentioned in comments, Targobank can perform actions for former Citibank customers.

Answer (score 3):

If the one in Goethestrasse was acceptable (before it changed into a TargoBank), then it would seem that according to [their website](http://www.yellowmap.de/D_04103_Leipzig/0/CBZW_Citibank+Filiale.htm):

There is one in Lützowstrasse as well.

> Lützowstr. 9-13
>
> 04155 Leipzig
>
> 0341 99737-0

Comment: it's targobank too, like all former citibank branches

Comment: @Dirty-flow in which case either would work, if they're offering the services he describes :)

Comment: yes, but your answer says that there is a citibank branch in Lützowstraße

Comment: Well, there IS, according to their website, it's just as you mention, it's now a TangoBank.  Much like in NZ when Trust Bank got taken over by Westpac (briefly WestpacTrust), all the Trust Bank brances were still there, they just had Westpac brandings.

Comment: the link you shared is not their website, it's an online adressbook, and as you can see it's not up to date